# Spring AMQP - how to set arguments on a Queue?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm try to set arguments on a queue, however Spring's `Queue` class doesn't have a setter method for arguments.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/core/Queue.html

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear! You just missed ctor for that: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/core/Queue.html#Queue-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-boolean-java.util.Map-

As you see that class is immutable and you can provide properties only through the ctors.

Comment: Woops, I missed that! Thanks!